# How to change element after render from .map method in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically, I am rendering out an array of say, 5 items. On a button click, I would like to text of the element to red. But only that specific element, AFTER the .map method has rendered out my array.

Take the following for example.

```
function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <ul>
        {numbers.map((number) => {
          return (
            <>
              <li key={Date.now()}>{number}</li>
              <button>Click me to make the text red!</button>
            </>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Now, when you click the button, it will change the color of that specific element. So, if I clicked on the button next to number 3, number 3 would turn red and the other numbers would remain the same color.

How would I do that with a .map method?

Say I wanted to target

Comment: You're either asking about React.cloneElement, to clone an element you don't own, and mutate it, or you're asking about how to use React state to track changes over time.

Comment: Do you want the height to be of `200px` or `color` to be red or background color to be red

Comment: It doesn't matter, it's purely an example. I just want the button to only effect the specific element it is currently contained in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take help of  `useState` hook,

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-waterfall-c6187?file=/src/App.js:0-580)

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);

  const numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

  return (
    <div>
      {numbers.map((number) => {
        return (
          <>
            <li key={number} className={selected === number ? "highlight" : ""}>
              <p>{number}</p>
            </li>
            <button onClick={() => setSelected(number)}>
              Click me to change color of text!
            </button>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you want to select multiple elements to highlight then you can change the initial state to an array

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  const numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

  return (
    <div>
      {numbers.map((number) => {
        return (
          <>
            <li
              key={number}
              className={selected.includes(number) ? "highlight" : ""}
            >
              <p>{number}</p>
            </li>
            <button onClick={() => setSelected((state) => [...state, number])}>
              Click me to change color of text!
            </button>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you want to toggle the red color

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-http-n0omm?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: That is nearly there, however, what if I wanted to make more than one colour red?

Comment: what does that mean

Comment: You can change CSS accordingly. I've done some styling...

Comment: one number red* my mistake

Comment: Currently, only ONE number can be red, what if I wanted to select multiple?

Comment: code edited on sandbox, check [go to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-waterfall-c6187?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Then you can take an array in useState initial state and push the `number` in the array and when checking if the number is present in the array or not then you can use `selected.includes(number) ? "highlight" : ""`

Comment: If you want to toggle red color on clicking the button then see [codesanbox for toggling](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-http-n0omm?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by *remembering* the state of the active numbers and applying different styles or css classes if the `number` is active.

The example below uses `useState` with a `Set` to remember the active numbers is and the button's `onClick` to add/remove active numbers.

```js
function App() {
  const numbers = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
  const [activeNumbers, setActiveNumbers] = React.useState(React.useMemo(() => new Set(), []));

  return (
    <ul>
      {
        numbers.map(number => (
          <li key={number} className={activeNumbers.has(number) ? 'active' : 'inactive'}>
            <span>{number}</span>
            <button onClick={() => {
              if (activeNumbers.has(number)) {
                activeNumbers.delete(number);
              } else {
                activeNumbers.add(number);
              }
              setActiveNumbers(new Set(activeNumbers));
            }}>Click me to change color of text!</button>
          </li>
        ))
      }
    </ul>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: That is nearly there, however, what if I wanted to make more than one colour red?

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect your comment. In short, use a `Set` to keep track of more than one value.

Answer (score 0):

just look at the `handleHistoryClick` function it will select the parents and after that chose the first child which is `<p>number</p>` then add `dangers` class to that.

```
function App() {
    const numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

    const handleHistoryClick = event => {
        let el = event.target;
        let newEl = el.parentNode.firstChild;
        newEl.classList.add("dangers");
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            {numbers.map(number => {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <li key={Date.now()}>
                            <p>{number}</p>
                            <button onClick={handleHistoryClick}>
                                Click me to change color of text!
                            </button>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

```
.dangers{
  color: red;
}
```